# How to post a picture on instagram using python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, scrapy, instapy

I want to post a picture on instagram using python but i don't know how to do it.
Thanks in advance.
i do this

But this was a fail

```
from instapy_cli import client
def post_instagram():
    capture()
    username = 's' 
    password = '' 
    image = 'photo.png'
    speak("what is the caption?")
    caption = command()
    text = "nice"
    with client(username, password) as cli:
        cli.upload(image, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  *capture()* and *caption= command()* and your code works fine. Like this

```
from instapy_cli import client

username = ' YOUR USERNAME'
password = 'YOUR PASSWORD'
image = 'image.jpg'
text = "nice"

with client(username, password) as cli:
    cli.upload(image, text)
```

Comment: I think insta_pi is no longer supported